# Having trouble binding strings to a PDO query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to bind variables to a PHP PDO query

The variables $breed_var, $species_var & $year_var represent form inputs so they might be integers or empty/null

Here's my code :

```
<?php

$breed_var = 11;
$species_var = 'species';
$year_var = 2016;

echo "<h1>Test</h1>";

$db_servername = "xxx";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_password = "xxx";
$db_dbName = "xxx";

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_servername;dbname=$db_dbName", $db_username, $db_password);
$pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn = $pdo;

    $query = '  SELECT *
                FROM livestock
                WHERE breed = :breed AND species = :species AND YEAR(date_of_birth) = :year
                ORDER BY species, livestock_name';
    $sql = $conn -> prepare($query);
    $sql -> bindValue(':species', $species_var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql -> bindValue(':year', $year_var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql -> bindValue(':breed', $breed_var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql -> execute();

$conn = null;

$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<p>species :: $species_var, year:: $year_var, breed: $breed_var</p>";
print_r($sql);
echo "<br /><br />";
print_r($row);
echo "<br /><br />";

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<p>$row[uk_tag_no] :: $row[livestock_name]</p>";
}

?>
```

If I run the following in MySQL it returns results:

```
SELECT *
FROM livestock
WHERE breed = 11 AND species = species AND YEAR(date_of_birth) = 2016
ORDER BY species, livestock_name
```

If I change

```
$species_var = 'species';
```

to

```
$species_var = 1;
```

it works so the issue must be the binding ?

Here's the DB table:

```
CREATE TABLE `livestock` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `species` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `livestock_name` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `uk_tag_no` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `previous_tags` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `for_slaughter` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `pedigree_no` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_sale` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_death` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mother` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `father` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_bred` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `origin` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `breed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notes` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You can debug it by binding the params positionally and see if that might have an effect.

Comment: `species = species` is returning all rows...

Comment: If you miss out the `AND species = species` part in your SQL (which is comparing the field against itself) what value do you get in the species field?

Comment: Please show us a `SHOW CREATE TABLE livestock`;

Comment: and since it is working when you change to a number I guess spieces is not a string field in your database

Comment: Do you have a cross reference table that links nice names to numeric codes, for the species

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes I do, I removed all the joins from the SQL for simplicity ;)

Comment: Use aliases and reference the correct field on the correct table? `select * from livestock l join species s on s.id = l.species where s.name = :species`. I don't know the species table schema so I am speculating. Also, `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default so you don't have to specify and year looks like it should actually be `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like `species = species`. Parameters are always treated as if they are values, not column names. So it will be as if you had written the condition `species = 'species'`.

But your species column is an integer, so comparing an integer column to a string will implicitly cast the string as an integer. In MySQL, the integer value of a string is based on any leading numeric digits in the string, then it ignores the non-numeric characters. So the integer value of `'species'` is 0.

It ultimately works as if you had made the condition `species = 0`.

---

Re comments:

It doesn't have to be messy to make an SQL query with search terms depending on the inputs. I do it frequently. Here's an example based on your case:

```
$params = [];
$terms = [];
if ($species_var) {
    $params['species'] = $species_var;
    $terms[] = 'species = :species';
}
if ($breed_var) {
    $params['breed'] = $breed_var;
    $terms[] = 'breed = :breed';
}
if ($year_var) {
    $params['year'] = $year_var;
    $terms[] = 'YEAR(date_of_birth) = :year';
}
if ($terms) {
    $whereClause = 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $terms);
}

$query = "  SELECT *
            FROM livestock
            $whereClause
            ORDER BY species, livestock_name";
$sql = $conn -> prepare($query);
$sql -> execute($params);
```

Comment: Using 'species = species' will simply return ALL species. At other points I will be using 'breed = breed' & 'YEAR(date_of_birth) = YEAR(date_of_birth)'.

This works in MySQL - it's as if the specific WHERE clause doesn't exist

Comment: That's not the way query parameters work. The parameter value is combined with the query as if it's a string literal, not a column name.

Comment: @PatDobson But why do that in the first place? It's like adding `AND 1 = 1`. If you want to have that in your code for some reason then you don't need it as a parameter. just add `AND spieces = spieces` instead of `species = :species`

Comment: There are three variables sent from form, 'breed', 'species' & 'year'. Any combination can be set to integers or left empty. So I can filter on 'breed' & 'year' OR 'species' & 'breed' OR 'year' OR 'breed' etc...

Comment: Then I guess you have to switch sql queries depanding on which fields you have available, I don't know if you can do it with only one query using prepared statements

Comment: @Dimitris Filippou - That going to make some MESSY code ! I was trying to avoid it